# Sobre la información de las wikis de etiquetas

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

He notado que la información de las wikis de las etiquetas que se han venido realizando en su gran mayoría provienen de la información análoga del sitio en inglés, pero en algunas etiquetas se está incluyendo como referencia o información adicional enlaces a páginas web en inglés. Considerando que este sitio está orientado a hablantes de español ¿es adecuado incluir enlaces a sitios en inglés en la edición de las wikis de etiquetas?

Answer (score 2):

Si te refieres a las ligas a los sitios de referencia "canónica" de algún lenguaje o tema, creo que en algunos casos es inevitable... después de todo, muchas páginas de referencia "canónica" están en inglés (por ejemplo, https://www.r-project.org/ , https://www.python.org/ , etcétera).

Dicho esto, si existen sitios de referencia en español, siempre será preferible incluirlos (por ejemplo https://secure.php.net/manual/es/index.php).